# PHP: Alter table but only in special columns

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add a column to only a specific user. if for an example i would like to add a new column but only to id 3.

**Here is the code that i'm using:**

```
$add = "ALTER TABLE $db_chest_name ADD kg_$countt INT(11) NOT NULL WHERE id='$myid'";
        mysql_query($add) or die ('could not alter ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please take a SQL tutorial. It seems like you don't understand the basic structure of a DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER` by default will add the column to the table not corresponding with the rows.If you want you can implement the logic on creating a column with default value and update it for the user whom you want.

Comment: @MGreeds this is true... you lack basic understanding of a database... you cannot have a column just for a specific user, it's a non-scene... To verify what we are saying, go to phpmyadmin and try to manually add a column to a specific user_id and you will see what we are talking about